# Cant refresh JWT Token "Signature has expired."

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using django-rest-framework-jwt and react-redux for my SPA.

Need refresh token that expires in 5 minutes. 
Refresh works during the 5 minutes. 
After it does not work, console show this error:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/auth/api-token-refresh/ 400 (Bad Request)
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)
```

and postman show this:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Signature has expired."
    ]
}
```

there's the middleware's code

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as urls from "../helpers/url";
import { authUpdateToken } from "../actions/auth";

const jwthunk = ({ dispatch, getState }: any) => (next: any) => (action: any) => {
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    if (getState().auth && getState().auth.token) {
      const currentToken = getState().auth.token;

      verifyToken(currentToken)
        .then((tokenVerified: any) => {
          refreshToken(tokenVerified, dispatch)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          refreshToken(currentToken, dispatch)
        })
    } else {
      console.log('Not Auth');
    }
  }
  return next(action);
}

export default jwthunk;

const verifyToken = async (token: any) => {
  const body = { token };
  let verifiedToken = '';

  await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/api-token-verify/', body)
    .then(({ data: { code, expires, token } }: any) => {
      verifiedToken = token;
    });

  return verifiedToken;
}

const refreshToken = async (token: any, dispatch: any) => {
  const body = { token }

  await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/api-token-refresh/', body)
    .then((response: any) => {
      dispatch(authUpdateToken({ token }));
    })
}
```

django-rest-framework-jwt send an unique token, without refresh-token

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there library have a flaw.
You cant refresh expired token..

**Solution**

1) Do a monkey patch in your code (Check the below commit code)
https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/pull/348

2)Switch to different library

3)you need to run a timer in you application(front end) and request for access token every 5 minutes before expiry. (which is not ideal way)